# How to activate django form.media javascript on an ajax loaded form?

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, forms, dajaxice

I have a little issue here :
I've got a form containing some media due to its widgets.
Everything works as expected when the form is part of the page but if I want to **load that form using an ajax call**, in a modal for example, even though the **js script is included** with the form, **it's not running**. The **css is working perfectly fine** on the other hand.

I guess this has something to do with **javascript not being able to detect a new script tag** has been included.

### What should I need to do to run this js ?

Code sample :

modal form template :

```
{{form.media}}
{% crispy form %}
<a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
```

template rendered inside modal :

```
<div id="level-modal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal="">
  <link href="/static/ajax_upload/css/ajax-upload-widget.css" type="text/css" media="all" rel="stylesheet">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/ajax_upload/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/ajax_upload/js/ajax-upload-widget.js"></script>
  <form id="level-form" class="foundation-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>
  <a class="close-reveal-modal">×</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you can just run the js after your ajax call has returned a status of complete. Maybe post your ajax code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I finally found the correct way to enable loaded javascript files.
Note that **jquery is required**.
It's a simple `$.ajax({{dataType: "script", cache: true, url: "url/file.js"}})`

As I was talking about form.media, you can retrieve all scripts needed by the form doing this :

```
files_url = []
for js in form.media._js: # for all the scripts used by the form
    files_url.append(form.media.absolute_path(js)) # we retrieve their url
```

As I'm using dajax to enable the scripts, I can make a simple call to `dajax.script` to enable the scripts :

```
loaders = []
for js in level_form.media._js:
    loaders.append('$.ajax({{dataType: "script", cache: true, url: "{0}"}})'.format(level_form.media.absolute_path(js)))

dajax.script("""
    $.when(
        {0}
    ).done(function() {{
        console.log("scripts are loaded !");
        // do something here when files are loaded
    }}).fail(function () {{ 
        alert("An error occured, try reloading the page.");
        // do something here if loading failed
    }});""".format(",\n".join(loaders)))
```

**Beware !** You'll need to add `DAJAXICE_XMLHTTPREQUEST_JS_IMPORT = False`
 in your settings.py, see [this subject for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28131424/ajax-with-django-fails/).